# Time parsing issue on Android

Tags: java, android, time, parseexception, datetime-parsing

I am getting a parse exception when trying to parse the time string `02:22 p.m.`.

I have the following conversion function:

```
public static long convertdatetotimestamp(String datestring, String newdateformat, String olddateformat){
    SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(olddateformat,Locale.ROOT);
    SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(newdateformat,Locale.ROOT);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = originalFormat.parse(datestring);
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
        Date parsedDate = targetFormat.parse(formattedDate);
        long nowMilliseconds = parsedDate.getTime();

        return nowMilliseconds;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The method is called in another activity with a time format `"02:22 p.m."`. `olddateformat` and `newdateformat` are the same: `hh:mm a`.

It causes following error in log:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02:22 p.m." (at offset 6)

How to resolve this issue? Time is in exactly above mentioned format.

Comment: And what's the value of `olddateformat` and `newdateformat` variables?

Comment: both are same _ "hh:mm a"

Comment: I believe that `SimpleDateFormat` can't be customized to parse `p.m.` (it only recognizes `PM`). Also, to get the `nowMilliseconds` value, you need all date fields (day/month/year) and a timezone. `SimpleDateFormat` will set this to January 1st of 1970 (and also set the seconds to zero), and use the system's default timezone. Is that what you want?

Comment: i'm able to get nowMilliseconds if the time format is in  "02:22 PM". Is there any possible format for parsing p.m. type?

Comment: It is if you remove the dots (I'm afraid that's the only way). But do you understand that `nowMilliseconds` is a [timestamp](https://currentmillis.com/) value? (the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`). This value depends not only on the hour, but also on the day, month, year and a timezone. `SimpleDateFormat` sets default values for it (see my previous comment), but is that what you really need?

Comment: If I run this code in my machine, it uses my system's default timezone (America/Sao_Paulo), and the result is 62520000. But if I change the timezone to another (let's say, `Asia/Kolkata`), the result is 31920000. For what do you need this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following changes that i've made works fine for me.

```
 public static long convertdatetotimestamp(String datestring, String newdateformat, String olddateformat){
        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(olddateformat,Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateFormat targetFormat = new
                SimpleDateFormat(newdateformat,Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = originalFormat.parse(datestring.replaceAll("\\.", ""));
            String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
            Date parsedDate = targetFormat.parse(formattedDate);
            long nowMilliseconds = parsedDate.getTime();

            return nowMilliseconds;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

**Locale.ENGLISH** you can use your locale, english solved my issue. [Reference.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DateFormat.html)

Thanks for responses and references.

Answer (score 3):

It so happens that a.m. and p.m. are called just this in Gaelic locale. At least on my Java 8. I am far from sure that it will be the case on (all) Android phones, but you may do some experiments with it.

```
String datestring = "02:22 p.m.";
Locale parseLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("ga");
DateTimeFormatter originalFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", parseLocale);
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse(datestring, originalFormat));
```

This prints

> 14:22

As Hugo so warmly and rightly recommends is [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239113/5772882), I am using the modern Java date and time API, so you will need ThreeTenABP for the above code. See [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Alternatively you may want to try the same locale with your otherwise outdated `SimpleDateFormat`.

US Spanish locale shows the same behaviour on my Java 8, so you may try that too: `Locale.forLanguageTag("es-US")`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `SimpleDateFormat` can't be customized to parse the `p.m.` part (it only recognizes `AM` or `PM`).

So one alternative is to remove the dots:

```
String time = "02:22 p.m.";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ROOT);
date = format.parse(time.replaceAll("\\.", ""));
```

One detail: to get the `nowMilliseconds` value, you need all the date fields (day/month/year) and a timezone. As those fields are not in the input `String`, `SimpleDateFormat` sets them to **January 1<sup>st</sup> of 1970** (and also set the seconds and milliseconds to zero), and use the system's default timezone.

*I'm not sure if this behaviour of getting January 1970 is consistent among all Java versions, which is another problem because you can get different values depending on the environment/device the code is running. Actually, you might have a different result anyway because it uses the system's default timezone and this can vary among different environments.*

If I run this code in my machine, it uses my system's default timezone (`America/Sao_Paulo`), and the result is `62520000`. But if I change the timezone to another (let's say, `Asia/Kolkata`), the result is `31920000`. You must be aware of this variation and check if that's what you really need.

Another detail is that, if `olddateformat` and `newdateformat` are the same, there's no need to create 2 different formatters.

---

## Java's new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. You'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

All the relevant classes are in the `org.threeten.bp` package.

With this new API, you can customize the text that corresponds to AM/PM using a `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` (so no need to remove the dots manually). And there are specific classes to each case - in this case, the input has only the time fields (hour and minutes), so I'm going to use the `org.threeten.bp.LocalTime` class (which represents only a time - hour/minute/second/nanosecond - without a date):

```
String time = "02:22 p.m.";
// map AM and PM values to strings "a.m." and "p.m."
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
map.put(0L, "a.m.");
map.put(1L, "p.m.");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // hour and minute
    .appendPattern("hh:mm ")
    // use custom values for AM/PM
    .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, map)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);

// parse the time
LocalTime parsedTime = LocalTime.parse(time, fmt);
```

The `parsedTime` variable will contain the values corresponding to `02:22 PM` (and only this value, it has no date fields (day/month/year) nor a timezone).

To get the milliseconds value ([number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`](https://currentmillis.com/)), you also need a date (day/month/year) and a timezone. As I said previously, those fields can affect the final value.

In the old API, `SimpleDateFormat` tries to be "smart" and sets default values for those fields (**January 1<sup>st</sup> of 1970** in the system's default timezone), but the new API is more strict about that and you must tell explicity what date and timezone you want.

In this example, I'm using the `Asia/Kolkata` timezone but you can change it according to your needs (more on that below):

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime;

// timezone for Asia/Kolkata
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
// current date in Kolkata timezone
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(zone);
// get the parsed time at the specified date, at the specified zone
ZonedDateTime zdt = parsedTime.atDate(now).atZone(zone);
// get the millis value
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

If you want a specific date instead of the current date, you can use `LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 20)` - this will get **May 20<sup>th</sup>, 2017**, for example. With this, you can set the code above to the date and timezone you need.

Note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Asia/Kolkata`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `IST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

---

If you want to emulate exactly what `SimpleDateFormat` does, you can use `LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1)` and use the default timezone with `ZoneId.systemDefault()` - but this is not recommended, because the system's default can be changed without notice, even at runtime. It's better to explicit what timezone you're using.

Or you can create a formatter that always sets default values for the date (using the `org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoField` class) and always uses the same timezone. So you can parse it directly to a `org.threeten.bp.Instant` and get the millis value:

```
String time = "02:22 p.m.";
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // hour and minute
    .appendPattern("hh:mm ")
    // use custom values for AM/PM (use the same map from previous example)
    .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, map)
    // default value for day: 1
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    // default value for month: January
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
    // default value for year: 1970
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 1970)
    // create formatter at my specific timezone
    .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT).withZone(zone);
// get the millis value
long millis = Instant.from(fmt2.parse(time)).toEpochMilli();
```